# Play Store - When turn on managed google play , internal app sharing and internal testing does not work

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

I used internal app sharing and internal testing, but now both service could not be able to work, I can only see satelite picture with "try again".

To my mind, I think this insident was occured when managed google play was turnd on for imports managed google play.

Of course I asked a question for google play store help ,before this option turned on.

"When turn on managed google play, internal test track will be continue for internal testers?"

play stores help stuff replaied by e-mail "yes, managed google play affecting only closed test truck, so release truck and internal test truck will be remains for public"

But when this options turned on ,this insident was occuerd.
I want to help by Google play store stuff ,but they says "this question was not known for us. ask a managed google play help".
I did not get any information by Managed google play's help.

Please would you teach me , how to turn off managed google play by play store, or how to use internal app sharing / internal testing without consideration of managed google play setting.

Comment: Directly move on to the ```production``` tab. You can skip those testing.

Comment: Following Same issue here!